# How to combine jQuery SlimScroll and sortableUI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wish to have two slimscrolled div and be able to drag and drop elements between them. The latter is tested, and is working perfectly with the [sortable](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) method, but when I apply the slimscrolls, the two divs receive the `overflow: hidden` attribute, which makes the dragged elements disappear when moved outside of the div. As per [documentation](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll/) I saw no option to modify the slimscroll's overflow attribute, which I would like to change to `overflow-x: visible` and `overflow-y: hidden`, for obvious reasons. The CSS attribute is applied on element level, so workaround with CSS rules are not an option afaik.

I want the slimscroll to be functional, but I want to be able to drag and drop elements between the two slimscrolled divs. How to proceed?

**EDIT**

In hope of receiving answer I add a code example:

```
<div id="container1">
  <ul><li>...</li></ul>
</div>

<div id="container2">
  <ul><li>...</li></ul>
</div>

<script>
  $('#container1').slimScroll({...});
  $('#container2').slimScroll({...});
  $('#container1').sortable({
    connectWith: "#container2",
  });
</script>
```

In the above example, elements from #container1 should be dragged to #container2, but due to the `overflow:hidden` property applied by the `slimScroll()`, the dragged element will disappear when dragged outside of the area of `#container1`. I wish to be able to drag the element and also see the element I am dragging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a setting in jquery.slimscroll.js. In v1.3.8 starting from the 160th line I did the following;

```
// wrap content
    var wrapper = $(divS)
      .addClass(o.wrapperClass)
      .css({
        position: 'relative',
        overflow: 'visible', // <--- change this from 'hidden' to 'visible' !!!
        width: o.width,
        height: o.height
      });
```

After applying the above change, the problem I described ceased to exist.